# Having problems binding my datagrid to data from my database

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, datagrid

i've a problem to use datagrid in wpf mvvm project

Here is my xaml :

```
<Window xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:dxe="http://schemas.devexpress.com/winfx/2008/xaml/editors" 
        x:Class="noteManager.MainWindow"
        xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:noteManager.ViewModel"
        DataContext="{StaticResource noteManagerViewModel}"
        Title="NoteManager" Height="490" Width="525">
    <Grid Margin="0,0,0,-132.5">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="10"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="50"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="200"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="40"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="110"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="111"></RowDefinition>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="10"></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="80"></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="100"></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="80"></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="100"></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="50"></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="50"></ColumnDefinition>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <TextBlock Text="Login :" FontSize="16" Grid.Column="2" Margin="51,9,50,0" Grid.RowSpan="2" Height="23" VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"/>
        <TextBox Text="{Binding Login}" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="3" Margin="14,0,86,29" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"/>
        <Button Background="LightGreen" Foreground="Green" Command="{Binding testConnexion}" x:Name="testConnexion" Content="Connexion" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" Margin="51,29,86,0" Grid.ColumnSpan="3"/>
        <Button Command="{Binding addUser}" Content="+" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="4" Margin="34,1,20,0" RenderTransformOrigin="0.742,0.468"/>

        <DataGrid Name="dataGrid1"  Grid.Row="2" Margin="8,7,-22,7" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
                  ItemsSource="{Binding _DataGridNotes}" SelectedItem="{Binding Path=MySelectedNote}" HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                  Width="480" Grid.ColumnSpan="6" Grid.Column="1">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Width="100" Binding="{Binding Path=NoteTitle}" Header="Titre" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Width="200" Binding="{Binding Path=NoteContent}" Header="Note" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Width="100" Binding="{Binding Path=NoteCreatedAt}" Header="Date de création" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Width="100" Binding="{Binding Path=NoteUpdatedAt}" Header="Dat MAJ" />
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>

        <TextBlock Text="Titre" FontSize="16" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1" Margin="27,8,7,1"/>
        <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=titre, Mode=TwoWay}" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="2" Margin="17,10,23,10" Grid.ColumnSpan="5"/>
        <TextBlock Text="Note" FontSize="16" Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="1" Margin="27,4,7,0"/>
        <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=description, Mode=TwoWay}" Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="2" Margin="17,10,23,8" Grid.ColumnSpan="5"/>
        <Button Command="{Binding Path=DeleteNote}" Background="LightPink" Foreground="red" Content="Supprimer" Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="1" Margin="55,7,26,81" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"/>
        <Button Command="{Binding Path=UpdateANote}" Content="Mettre à jour" Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="3" Margin="14,7,67,81" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5"/>
        <Button Command="{Binding Path=AddNote}" Content="Ajouter" Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="4" Margin="78,7,10,81" Grid.ColumnSpan="3"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Here is my viewModel :

```
namespace noteManager.ViewModel
{
    public class noteManagerViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        void Notify(string property)
        {
            if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(property));
            }
        }

        string login;
        int currentUser;
        public string Login
        {
            get
            {
                return login;
            }
            set
            {
                login = value; Notify("Login");
            }
        }
        private bool _canExecute;

        public noteManagerViewModel()
        {
            _canExecute = true;
        }

        private ICommand _testConnexion;
        public ICommand testConnexion
        {
            get
            {
                return _testConnexion ?? (_testConnexion = new CommandHandler(() => Connexion(), _canExecute));
            }
        }

        private ICommand _addUser;
        public ICommand addUser
        {
            get
            {
                return _addUser ?? (_addUser = new CommandHandler(() => AjoutUser(), _canExecute));
            }
        }

        private ObservableCollection<DataGridNotes> _DataGridNotes = new ObservableCollection<DataGridNotes>();

        public ObservableCollection<DataGridNotes> dataGridNotes
        {
            // No need for a public setter
            get { return _DataGridNotes; }
        }
}
```

the other class that i use :

```
public class User
    {
        /*public User()
        {
            this.Note = new HashSet<Note>();
        }*/

        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Login { get; set; }

        //public virtual ICollection<Note> Note { get; set; }
    }

    public class Note : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string NoteText { get; set; }
        public string ContentText { get; set; }
        public DateTime CreatedAt { get; set; }
        public DateTime? UpdatedAt { get; set; }
        public int UserId { get; set; }

        //public virtual User User { get; set; }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        public void Notify(string property)
        {
            if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(property));
            }
        }
    }
    public class DataGridNotes
    {
        private string _noteTitle;
        private string _noteContent;
        private string _noteCreatedAt;
        private string _noteUpdatedAt;

        public string NoteTitle { get { return _noteTitle; } set { _noteTitle = value; } }
        public string NoteContent { get { return _noteContent; } set { _noteContent = value; } }
        public string NoteCreatedAt { get { return _noteCreatedAt; } set { _noteCreatedAt = value; } }
        public string NoteUpdatedAt { get { return _noteUpdatedAt; } set { _noteUpdatedAt = value; } }
    }
```

sorry for the ugly code, new to c# for a project.

i want to use the datagrid in my viewmodel but don't find a way to make it work (would like to write data from mysql database in the datagrid

Have you an idea to make it work ?

thx in advance

Comment: Does your VS output window show binding errors? I'd guess it would complain that it can't find a property called `_DataGridNotes`. You've defined a *private backing field* called that, for your public property `dataGridNotes`. Change your binding to `ItemsSource="{Binding dataGridNotes}"`.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, It's tough to spot what you are doing wrong without seeing the ViewModel, however you may want to check the following:

1) The DataContext is correct.

2) The property _DataGridNotes exists. Check the program output to make sure that there are no warnings informing you that bindings are broken.

The property you are looking to have should look something like this:

```
List<Note> _DataGridNotes
{
    get
    {
        // get notes from SQL request
        // construct list of Note and return list
    }
}
```

You should also make sure that the Note class contains the properties required (NoteTitle, NoteContent, NoteCreatedAt, NoteUpdatedAt).

It might also be worth passing back some dummy notes to debug if the problem lies in the request to the SQL database.

Comment: Hello, thx for the help by still don't saw how to use the datagrid, i've add information to my first post !

Comment: some anonymous user proposed following edit: "It looks like you are binding to a private observable collection when you should be binding to dataGridNotes (not _DataGridNotes). E.g. `ItemsSource="{Binding dataGridNotes}"`"

Comment: And another user (@lagunag) just proposed the same edit. @lagunag, if you think this answer is wrong just write your version as a comment, or even a full answer (if it is too long or if you cannot comment). Do not use the edit function to correct the post of someone else.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are trying to bind to a private Observable collection _DataGridNotes where you should be binding to the property dataGridNotes:

```
ItemsSource="{Binding dataGridNotes}"
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts if you are having problems with multiple accounts.